# Javascript and the DOM issues

Tags: javascript, dom

I am having a trouble using Vanilla Javascript and the DOM. In my html code i have some p elements and some h2 elements. I am trying to target them with javascript just to train of using the DOM. Here is my Javascript code:

```
var allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var h = document.querySelectorAll("h2");

for ( i=0; i <= allP.length; i++){
    allP[i].classList.add("hello"), allP[i].style.color = "red";
};

for (i=0; i<=h.length; i++){
    h[i].style.color = "orange";
}
```

The **P** tag elements are getting the **hello** class and the style **color to red**. However when i continue with the **h2** tag they do not get their color to change. Moreover if i remove the **allP** var and the **for loop**, the **h2 for loop** works fine. Anyone can explain why this is happening? Also i have some **li** elements and some **a** tags but as soon as the first **for loop** kicks in the other **for loops** below the first one does not work.

Thanks

Comment: you are using an `i` variable with global scope, start changing the letter for the second loop as a test.

Comment: Also I recommend to use the semicolon rather than the comma as statement separator and you do not want to use `<=` but just `<`

Comment: Your first loop contains a comma (,) when it should contain a semi-colon (;)  instead. You've got two seperate statements on the same line, so you need to terminate the first one. Comma doesn't do this, the semi-colon does. Also, you should go from i=0 up to i<length; The last valid index is one less than the number of elements in an array,since they're zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `i < xxx.length` in the loops length to avoid an error. The length of the loop for example could be 3 so the loop will target the elements `allP[0]`, `allP[1]` and `allP[2]`.

```js
var allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var h = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
var i;
for ( i=0; i < allP.length; i++){
  allP[i].classList.add("hello");
  allP[i].style.color = "red";
};

for (i=0; i < h.length; i++){
  h[i].style.color = "orange";
}
```

```html
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>

<h2>h2a</h2>
<h2>h2b</h2>
<h2>h2c</h2>
<h2>h2d</h2>
```

Comment: Why would he need different vars? The loops are not overlapping and he resets the i between them

Comment: Right, edited, anyway I think is a good practice to avoid side effects.

Comment: This `i <= allP.length -1` makes my hair crawl

Comment: @mplungjan Could you please explain a little your comment?

Comment: @LionelT It's more idiomatic to use `< length` than `<= length-1`.

Comment: PLEASE use `i < allP.length` ALWAYS - or even better: `for (var i=0, n=allP.length;i<n;i++);`

Comment: `i < arr.length` and `i <= arr.length - 1` are equivalent, but the former is generally preferred as it's easier to read.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, just leave the code as it was. Absolutely agree, edited.

Comment: @NoName84 Please see the updated answer since it is now more correct when the comma is changed to a semicolon and the `i` is declared as `var i`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're getting an error in the first loop, so the second loop never executes. You need to change `i <= allP.length` to `i < allP.length` (and similarly for the second loop). Array indexes run from `0` to `length-1`, but you're trying to assign to properties of `allP[allP.length]`. Since this is undefined, calling `undefined.classList.add()` gets an error.

Also, you should separate the two operations with `;`, not `,`. It happens to work the way you wrote it, because of the way the comma operator works, but it's not good style -- this is not one of the situations where the comma operator is needed.

And it's good practice to declare loop variables local with `var`.

```
for (var i=0; i < allP.length; i++){
    allP[i].classList.add("hello");
    allP[i].style.color = "red";
};

for (i=0; i < h.length; i++){
    h[i].style.color = "orange";
}
```

Comment: And to make everyone happy, define `var i;` before the first loop :)

Comment: Or in the first loop, as I've added.

Comment: I would always have them both since one day I will decide to move the second loop to another scope and then i is global again

Answer (score 0):

Try using another variable in the second loop, for example `j`:

```
var allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var h = document.querySelectorAll("h2");

for (var i=0; i <= allP.length; i++){
    allP[i].classList.add("hello"), allP[i].style.color = "red";
};

for (var j=0; j<=h.length; j++){
    h[j].style.color = "orange";
}
```

Comment: Or the same with the var in front and there is one more error in the <=

Comment: @mplungjan it's not the same. Both `i` and `j` here are hoisted up to the same scope as `allP` and `h`, so you'd be (wrongly) re-declaring `i`.

Comment: Using different variables is important when you have nested loops. I don't see how it can make a difference when the loops don't overlap.

Comment: Never bothered my JS interpreters none: https://jsfiddle.net/ttk7vraw/ - the loops are not nested as @Barmar said

Comment: You can redeclare variables in JS, but [it's not a good practice](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare).

Comment: I consider it good practice if you have several unrelated loops in the same function. Otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, you have a scoping issue.  You can still use i for both loops, just declare it with var so its not globally scoped.  There's also an issue with `i <= arr.length` you need to make it `i <= arr.length - 1`.

```
var allP = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var h = document.querySelectorAll("h2");

for ( var i=0; i <= h.length - 1; i++){
    h[i].style.color = "orange";
}

for ( var i=0; i <= allP.length - 1; i++){
    allP[i].classList.add("hello"); 
    allP[i].style.color = "red";
};
```

**Update**  I was incorrect on the scoping, that's not the issue here.  I assumed that var declaration inside loop initialization made variables that were local to the loop, but they're actually scoped to the same scope the loop is running in.

The problem occurs only because of the issue with using `h.length` instead of `h.length - 1` (or using `<` instead of `<=`).

Comment: The second `var` is not needed, since the second loop is in the same scope as the first.

Comment: The loops are not overlapping, it's not a scoping problem.